# How to update datagridview items in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to update invoice and invoice has multiple items i retrieve invoice items from Database to `DataGridView` now user can remove the items and can add the items and user will click on update button to update the invoice in database.

My Code:

```
try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand sc = new SQLiteCommand("Update Orders Set [Order_No] = @Order_No,[Order_Type] = @Order_Type,[Order_Date] = @Order_Date,[Customer_Name] = @Customer_Name,[Contact] = @Contact,[Adress] = @Adress,[Delivery_Address] = @Delivery_Address,[Rider] = @Rider,[Items] = @Items,[Price] = @Price,[Qty] = @Qty,[Item_Total] = @Item_Total,[Item_Cat] = @Item_Cat,[SubTotal] = @SubTotal,[Discount] = @Discount,[Total_Amount] = @Total_Amount,[Paid_Amount] = @Paid_Amount,[Change_Due] = @Change_Due,[Delivery_Charges] = @Delivery_Charges Where Order_No = '" + Order_No.Text + "' ", con))
                    {
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_No", Order_No.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Type", Order_Type.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Date", Order_Date.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", Customer_Name.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", Contact.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress", Address.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivery_Address", Delivery_Address.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rider", "");
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Total", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Cat", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[5].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTotal", SubTotal.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", Discount.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Amount", Total_Amount.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid_Amount", Paid_Amount.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change_Due", Change_Due.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivery_Charges", Del_Charges.Text);
                        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                SuccessBox sb = new SuccessBox();
                sb.lbl_Change.Text = Change_Due.Text;
                sb.label1.Text = "Successfully Updated";
                sb.ShowDialog();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

if i add new item and click on update button so this query replaces my all old items with new one.

Suppose i add Samsung S8 so it willl replace my old items to Samsung S8.

And the result is:

```
Samsung S8   1   $750
Samsung S8   1   $750
Samsung S8   1   $750
Samsung S8   1   $750
```

Is there any way to do this?

Note: I am unable to solve this problem 8 days passed now.

Comment: If you learn about data binding, updating the DB is a single simple method `myDataAdapter.Update();`

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 can you give me any example so i can do it by myself?